# Visual Studio throws error when I make a using directive for a project I referenced in my solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, ide

My solution (this is VS2010 Express) contains three projects.  One is my main project that uses Xna, the second is called MyExtendedContentProcessor, and the third is a blank class file identical to what you get when just add a new project (even called ClassLibrary1).  My main project can reference ClassLibrary1 if I add the reference, but if I add the reference to MyExtendedContentProcessor, I can add a using directive, but then when I build I get

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'TriangleProcessorExtension' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And after that intellisense will no longer see the namespace inside MyExtendedContentProcessor.  I'm really not sure why it is acting this way.  By the way, if I comment everything out of MyExtendedContentProcessor, it still does not let me add a reference to it.

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: (Taken from my comment) Also, not sure if this is related or not, but I'm unable to change my output path. I can change it, but it doesn't actually change where the files are being copied to, and if I restart Visual Studio, the build path is the same as it was before I changed it (even though I pressed save)

Comment: update your question with this new comment so others can read that info.. However what is the `target framework` on your build, if it were `.Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile` does changing it to `.NET Framework 4` apply "like you output path"?

Comment: You already shot down the .NET Framework Target setting as the cause.  It however *exactly* behaves like this when you have the client profile selected and you shouldn't.  Review the setting on all your projects.  Particularly look for a reference to System.Web in the class library project.

Comment: I went back and made sure that everything was set to framework 4 (not client profile), but nothing changed.  I am still able to add the statement "using MyExtendedContentProcessor;" once, after which building will result in "namespace could not be found" error, after which intellisense doesn't pick up the namespace until I remove the reference and readd it.

Comment: Make sure you don't have a circular reference. Also, look at the text of your .sln and .csproj files.  Make sure the reference is in there, because VS can do weird things at times.

Comment: Something seems to be fishy in .csproj file; you can right-click on "MainProject", Unload Project, edit csproj to verify. I'd look at Reference and ProjectReference tags. Or if you can paste that file to any pastebin like http://pastie.org, others may be able to advise.